# Manage multiple feeds import using cli

Tags: drush, performance, multi-sites, cron

How can I optimize multiple feed importer from cli?

Is there any way to optimize multisites using multicron for each site in drupal 7.?

I want to implement like this https://www.drupal.org/node/1294438

Looking for more description.

Comment: Please rewrite your question so that you are only asking one thing. If you are already asking one think please clarify your question mentioning what you've already tried.